# Using fread() to read contents of a file

Tags: c, fread

My goal is to use fread to read in the contents of a file and manually change the number of bytes read. Basically, I have to run the program with different sizes and then use the time program on the command line to record the running time of each size. I'm not supposed to print anything. Here is what I have written:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

#define BYTES 1

int main()
{
   FILE *fp = NULL;
   int read;
   char buff[BYTES];

   if ((fp = fopen("file.txt", "r")) == NULL)
   {
      printf("Error in opening the file.\n");
      exit(1);
   }
   else
   {
      read = fread(buff, sizeof(buff), BYTES, fp);
      while(read >= BYTES)
      {
         continue;
      }
   }

   fclose (fp);

   return 0;

}
```

I am testing the program with size 1 first, then going to increase the size after I run the time command and record the running time. However, when I call the time in the command line, nothing happens. My program is just stuck, and I would have to force quit the program. If someone could point to my error, that would be great. Thank you!

Comment: The program goes into an infinite loop. What are you trying to achieve with the while loop?

Comment: This is the time to learn [how to debug small programs](https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/).

Comment: Passing both `sizeof(buff)` and `BYTES` as sizes to `fread` works only because you have character arrays. If you have an array of `int` then it would not work and you would read more than the size of the array. The first size argument is the size of *each element* (in your case `sizeof buff[0]`), and the second size argument is the number of elements.

Comment: In my while loop, I'm trying to get it to read all the contents in the file but not print out anything

Comment: Also remember that `fread` can read less than requests, for example if you reach the end of the file. Then `fread` will return a value larger than zero, but less than the number of elements requested.

Comment: You don't do anything in yourr while loop.

Comment: Lastly about your problem: Where ***inside the loop*** do you ever modify the value of `read`? Try explaining the loop to your [rubber duck](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rubber_duck_debugging).

Comment: I think I see my error now. Would it be correct to make read = fread(buff, sizeof(buff), BYTES, fp) be in the while loop condition like so:
while((read = fread(buff, sizeof(buff[0]), BYTES, fp)) >= BYTES)

Answer (score 0):

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

#define BYTES 1

int main()
{
   FILE *fp = NULL;
   int read;
   char buff[BYTES];

   if ((fp = fopen("file.txt", "r")) == NULL)
   {
      printf("Error in opening the file.\n");
      exit(1);
   }
   else
   {
      
      while((read = fread(buff, sizeof(buff), BYTES, fp)) >= BYTES)
      {
         printf("%s",buff); //for debugging
         continue;
      }
      
   }

   fclose (fp);

   return 0;

}
```

you need to reassign the variable "read"
and you should use function printf in order to print these strings. :)

Comment: `>= BYTES)` that is odd - can `fread` return `> BYTES`? Also `sizeof(buff), BYTES` - that's `BYTES*BYTES `bytes, a lot more. You could `sizeof(char), BYTES` or `sizeof(buff), 1` or such combinations. `#define BYTES 1` and `char buff[BYTES];`  - 1 char can only store an empty string, wouldn't this code go into infinite loop? `fread` can't store anything in the ouptut, BYTES has to be at least 2.

Comment: yep You're right thanks!!
(oh, sorry for late reply... )